# PDF's and viruses in Django

Tags: python, django, security, pdf

I'm building a web application (python and Django) that allows users to upload pdf files for other users to download. How do I prevent a user from uploading a virus embedded in the pdf?

Update:
I found this code on django snippets that uses clamcv. Would this do the job?

```
def clean_file(self):
    file = self.cleaned_data.get('file', '')
    #check a file in form for viruses
    if file:
        from tempfile import mkstemp
        import pyclamav
        import os
        tmpfile = mkstemp()[1]
        f = open(tmpfile, 'wb')
        f.write(file.read())
        f.close()
        isvirus, name = pyclamav.scanfile(tmpfile)
        os.unlink(tmpfile)
        if isvirus:
            raise forms.ValidationError( \
            "WARNING! Virus \"%s\" was detected in this file. \
            Check your system." % name)

    return file
```

Comment: install a virus scanner and scan the file after upload and before it is stored...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in general you can use *any* virus scanning software to accomplish this task: Just

- generate a command line string which calls the virus scanner on your file
- use python subprocess to run the command line string like so:

  ```
  try:
      command_string = 'my_virusscanner -parameters ' + uploaded_file
      result = subprocess.check_output(command_string,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)
      #if needed, do something with "result"            
  except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
      #if your scanner gives an error code when detecting a virus, you'll end up here
      pass 
  except:
      #something else went wrong
      #check sys.exc_info() for info
      pass
  ```

Without checking the source code, I assume that `pyclamav.scanfile` is doning more or less the same - so if you trust [clamav](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/), you should be doing fine. If you don't trust ist, use the approach above with the virus scanner of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django-safe-filefield](https://github.com/mixkorshun/django-safe-filefield) package to validate that uploaded file extension match it MIME-type. Example:

*settings.py*

```
CLAMAV_SOCKET = 'unix://tmp/clamav.sock'  # or tcp://127.0.0.1:3310

CLAMAV_TIMEOUT = 30  # 30 seconds timeout, None by default which means infinite
```

*forms.py*

```
from safe_filefield.forms import SafeFileField

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    attachment = SafeFileField(
        scan_viruses=True,
    )
```

Comment: Hello @mixkorshun I used this package but when i upload file at admin side then this error occurred : `'FieldFile' object has no attribute 'content_type'`.When i send file by using `postman request` it works very well.